# Stuck at Ubuntu logo during installation

Tags: 16.04

I am a complete beginner.
I was installing Ubuntu and i got stuck at Ubuntu logo screen.
So here is what happened:
I wanted to dual boot windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
I disabled secure boot and fast startup from windows 10 and UEFI settings.
Made a bootable USB disk as shown on Ubuntu website using rufus.
When I booted with the usb stick, "at this time" the setup got stuck at the Ubuntu logo screen.
I can't do anything it just got stuck before anything happened.

I'm using Dell Inspiron 15
8gb ram, Intel 7th gen i5.

Now waiting for battery to die.
Please Help.

Comment: If you press the ESC key, the logo screen should disappear and you should see the textual boot logs and it should tell you what the problem is. If that doesn't work, try pressing key combinations Alt+F1 to Alt+F12 and see if you can get the textual boot logs which should tell you where the problem is. Post any error messages you see here but I have a feeling it would be related to finding the squashfs.

Comment: Nothing is working.

Comment: You can force-shutdown your system by holding the Power button continuously. Try a different UFD using the same procedure. Perhaps it's an issue with the drive.